# RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex does not work correctly. How to get the CORRECT line index in which the cursor currently is?

Tags: c#, indexing, cursor, line, richtextbox

I'm trying to find a way to get the line's index in which the cursor is currently blinking in a RichTextBox control, and display it in a Label.
First I've tried GetLineFromCharIndex(), but when I press an arrow key, it does not updates itself at the first time. I've created this example:

These are my lines:

```
this
is
my
example
```

when I wrote these, the line index was shown correctly. Now let's say my cursor is blinking right now in the fourth line (I = the cursor)

```
this
is
my
eIxample
```

The index is now correctly displayed as 3. But now if I press an up arrow key, the cursor will blink in the "my" line, but the index will be still 3.
If I write the indexes every time I pressed the up key to the console, the result looks like this:

```
//Output:
3
3
2
1
```

I've tried to use Regex and a foreach loop as well, but they gave me the perfectly same result.

Can anyone give me a good advice how to write a code that always updates and shows the correct index of the line in which the cursor currently is?

Thanks

Comment: What is the event that generates the output?

Comment: FUTURE READERS: `richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart)` solves the OP's problem. You can use this code from anywhere (logically, from anywhere where it is called). I have to highlight this issue here because the OP's comments below are quite misleading (not sure about the exact reason of this: he either has some problems to understand what was exactly wrong in his code or is not a too honest person).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably handling the `KeyDown` event of `RichTextBox`, which fires *before* the SelectionStart property is changed to the cursor position, so that method always gives you the line index for the previous cursor position. Handle the `KeyUp` event and your problem should be fixed:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    int lineIndex = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart);
    label1.Text = lineIndex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So... you are writing the same code than I did (= whole point of the question here) + assuming (assumptions not present in the original post) that the OP is calling his code from the KeyDown Event... Actually, there is a further limitation in your code: it only works when Keys.Down or Keys.Up is pressed (but not with Keys.Right, for example). You seriously think that your answer is adding anything to mine (on top of restricting it to work just with Keys.Up and Keys.Down)?

Comment: @varocarbas, I think it's obvious that the OP is already aware of the method and the property (he mentions the method at least), so I doubt that part is of any value, the key is the time that code is being fired which causes it to return the wrong value, so the assumption is the important part of this answer. Thanks for noting the limiting if statement though.

Comment: PS: no problem regarding the correction (here to help). Note that, even by forgetting about what I have explained right now (and by assuming that the OP is not able to debug the code to see if a given line is being executed or not); in your position, I would have written a comment to the valid answer (mine), saying something like "refer this bit, just in case" (I would have reply the same than in the comment above; but at least this information would have been reflected in the comments). I wouldn't ever have written a new answer basically not saying anything new. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: He mentioned GetLineFromCharIndex, but not SelectionStart. So he might be relying on a RTB event and taking the inputted character as argument to GetLineFromCharIndex, or something like this. I am reasonably sure that he is not using SelectionStart, because otherwise his code would work. What you are saying of KeyDown Event means that the part determining the specific line is not being even executed! What the OP might have discovered after a simple debugging (I assume that the OP can do a simple debugging by himself).

Comment: PS: no problem regarding the correction (here to help). Note that, even by forgetting about what I have explained right now (and by assuming that the OP is not able to debug the code to see if a given line is being executed or not); in your position, I would have written a comment to the valid answer (mine), saying something like "refer this bit, just in case" (I would have replied the same than above; but at least this information would have been reflected in the comments). I wouldn't ever have written a new answer basically not saying anything new. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @varocarbas calm down dude :D

Comment: (why so much people say that?!) I am very calmed. Just explaining the point, but very relaxed. This is the way in which I express myself (by explaining points with arguments).

Comment: Saeb, just to let you know (and to the up-voter voting your comment above and, presumably, your answer; that is: nothing to do with being right, but with having misunderstood my behaviour?! -> is this what SO is about?) that I have updated my profile to account for your recent inputs (saying to me calm down!? One of the most calmed person on earth??)... Also note that by applying one of the rules I am using to improve SO (as explained in my profile), I might delete my answer because of not wanting to promote certain kind of attitudes between askers (i.e., ungrateful/careless = no help from me)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Saeb! I could have never solve this issue without it. I've tried almost every event: KeyDown, KeyPress, PreviewKeyDown, and TextChanged, so that's everything except KeyUp. Silly me :P. But now it works fine! :)

Comment: @Richtenzorg You are welcome (don't need to say thanks). The problem didn't have nothing to do with the event, but with not having used the right code. Saeb code (a copy of mine, although written pretty long time afterwards) works fine on any event (or outside any RTB event). Logically, the code has to be triggered. This is to let you know that I have found your behaviour completely unappropriate and thus will not help you again. Also to help future readers to understand the problem: you are telling a partial and untrue version of the real problem here.

Comment: @varocarbas, again, the code is _not_ the important part and does not have anything to do with my answer, I just included it for the sake of completeness, I could as well _not even include it_, the important part was the **assumption** about the **timing** of the code, which turned out to be correct.

Comment: @Saeb I don't think that your answer together with the OP's comment (i.e., I tried lots of events and only the one you proposed worked) does provide accurate enough information for future readers. In any case, I do think that this small issue has been solved via my comment to the question. PS: "again"?! (not seeing the information in this comment in your previous ones). PPS: "sake of completeness"?! Converting a generic solution into a narrowly applicable one? Anyway... this discussion has got already too long and doesn't seem to have a point (my comment above includes all what is required).